# PyTorch multi-class: ValueError: Expected input batch_size (416) to match target batch_size (32)

Tags: nlp, pytorch, multiclass-classification

I have created a mutli-class classification neural network. Training, and validation iterators where created with BigBucketIterator method with fields {'text_normalized_tweet':TEXT, 'label': LABEL}

TEXT = a tweet
LABEL = a float number (with 3 values: 0,1,2)

Below I execute a dummy example of my neural network:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class MultiClassClassifer(nn.Module):
  #define all the layers used in model
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
    
    #Constructor
    super(MultiClassClassifer, self).__init__()

    #embedding layer
    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)

    #dense layer
    self.hiddenLayer = nn.Linear(embedding_dim, hidden_dim)

    #Batch normalization layer
    self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden_dim)

    #output layer
    self.output = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    #activation layer
    self.act = nn.Softmax(dim=1) #2d-tensor

    #initialize weights of embedding layer
    self.init_weights()

  def init_weights(self):

    initrange = 1.0
    
    self.embedding.weight.data.uniform_(-initrange, initrange)
  
  def forward(self, text, text_lengths):

    embedded = self.embedding(text)

    #packed sequence
    packed_embedded = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, text_lengths, batch_first=True)

    tensor, batch_size = packed_embedded[0], packed_embedded[1]

    hidden_1 = self.batchnorm(self.hiddenLayer(tensor))

    return self.act(self.output(hidden_1))
```

Instantiate the model

```
INPUT_DIM = len(TEXT.vocab)
EMBEDDING_DIM = 100
HIDDEN_DIM = 64
OUTPUT_DIM = 3

model = MultiClassClassifer(INPUT_DIM, EMBEDDING_DIM, HIDDEN_DIM, OUTPUT_DIM)
```

When I call

```
text, text_lengths = batch.text_normalized_tweet
                
predictions = model(text, text_lengths).squeeze()

loss = criterion(predictions, batch.label)
```

it returns,

> ValueError: Expected input batch_size (416) to match target batch_size (32).

```
model(text, text_lengths).squeeze() = torch.Size([416, 3])
batch.label = torch.Size([32])
```

I can see that the two objects have different sizes, but I have no clue how to fix this?

You may find the Google Colab notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HtohSU4oz_FwllYll0WgVtbaj4cI-FR2?usp=sharing)

Shapes of each in, out tensor of my forward() method:

```
torch.Size([32, 10, 100]) #self.embedding(text)
torch.Size([320, 100]) #nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, text_lengths, batch_first=True)
torch.Size([320, 64]) #self.batchnorm(self.hiddenLayer(tensor))
torch.Size([320, 3]) #self.act(self.output(hidden_1))
```

Comment: What's the dimension of `model(text, text_lengths)`? Why are you using `squeeze()`?

Comment: @kkgarg its ```torch.Size([416, 3])``` ...i think sueeze can be omitted. I am new with PyTorch so not all keywords are familiar to me. I have posted the shapes at the end.

Comment: To debug, I'd start with noting down the dimensions after every step in the forward pass. Finally, the output of `model(text, text_lengths)` should be [32, 3] if your batch_size is `32` and the number of classes = `3`. Try to refer to Pytorch documentation for the individual functions e.g. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss

Comment: @kkgarg the hidden_1 = self.batchnorm(self.hiddenLayer(tensor)) has shape [32, 13, 3] and output = self.act(self.output(hidden_1)) has shape [32x13, 3] = [416,3]

Comment: @kkgarg please check my update with the shapes per tensor in ```forward()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the `squeeze` function after the forward pass, that doesn't make sense.

After removing the `squeeze` function, as you see, the shape of your final output is `[320,3]` whereas it is expecting `[32,3]`. One way to fix this is to average out the embeddings you obtain for each word after the `self.Embedding` function like shown below:

```
def forward(self, text, text_lengths):

    embedded = self.embedding(text)
    embedded = torch.mean(embedded, dim=1, keepdim=True)

    packed_embedded = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(embedded, text_lengths, batch_first=True)
    tensor, batch_size = packed_embedded[0], packed_embedded[1]

    hidden_1 = self.batchnorm(self.hiddenLayer(tensor))
    return self.act(self.output(hidden_1))
```

Comment: Indeed averaging the embeddings makes sense and seems to fix the problem. I will accepts and upvote your answer. Moving to the next step ```loss.backward()``` I receive this error: ```IndexError: select(): index 1 out of range for tensor of size [1, 32, 100] at dimension 0 ``` Shall I create a new question to that or it's related to the embedding averaging.

Comment: That should be a separate question I guess